# Access the new ember router in the console

Tags: ember.js

Is there an equivalent function to grab the currentPath in the console with the new router in ember?

Before, I was able to do this:

```
App.router.get("currentPath")
```

However, it seems with the new router, you can't access the router in the same fashion. In fact App.router simply returns undefined.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

On a related note, because I can no longer access `App.router` and its properties, I can't figure out how to manually trigger state changes. For example,

```
App.router.transitionTo("some.state")
```

is no longer viable. What is everyone doing instead of this now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer buried in github issues. Re-posting here for posterity.

```
App.container.lookup('router:main').router
```

..returns the router. You can access transitionTo and handleURL to manually trigger state changes. Not exactly sure how to get the current state like before, but it seems like you can access the currentHandlerInfos property on the router to get an array of the current handlers (duh).

Hope this prevents someone else from ripping out their hair.

Comment: Thanks! I searched for some time in the source but was not able to find it. Very helpful thanks!

Comment: this is no longer viable, as it has been removed from the public api, apparently.

Comment: container has just been renamed to make it clear that this should not be used as a public api. For debugging purposes you can still access the router with: `App.__container__.lookup('router:main').router`

Answer (score 4):

As of the latest build, you can find the router and change state like so:

```
App.Router.router.transitionTo('posts.comments');
```

or

```
App.Router.router.handleURL('/posts/comments');
```

I don't know if this is the recommended way (the router is very much a moving target at this point), but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

As of Ember 3.9, here is the new Router Service API docs.

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/RouterService

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  router: inject(),

  actions: {
    next() {
      this.router.transitionTo('other.route');
    }
  }
});
```

Also here is an answer I posted about how to get the `currentPath` on the router service.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580684/4044548

Answer (score -2):

I think this should do

```
function getCurrentPath(){
  str = "currentState.parentState"
  arr = []
  arr.push(App.router.get("currentState.name"))
  while(true){
    name = App.router.get(str+".name");
    arr.push(name)
    str += ".parentState";
    if(name == "root"){
      break;
    }
  }
  return arr.reverse().join(".")
}

currentPath = getCurrentPath();
```

Comment: this is a rather unhelpful answer.. you seem to be completely ignoring the fact that App.router doesn't return anything anymore. So what'd be the point of doing what you're doing?

Comment: Oopsie, I must need to read the question properly :-/ , App.router.get("currentPath") doesn't return the path, So I did this, anyways this ones for the previous versions...Did you peek through the source code ? it might help

Comment: It's okay, I appreciate the effort, although my problem remains unsolved. I have, in fact, looked at the source (a bit actually), but it's a tricky thing to be looking for, since it effectively means I'm looking for something which is no longer implemented. I was hoping someone knew another way to be able to access those properties somehow.

Comment: I just had a look of the new router and thats alot of change at a time !

Comment: There's a relevant github issue thread [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1646).