# Emberjs - how to access router in RC1

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In emberjs **pre2** we could access router from any where like

```
App.get('router')
```

Can anybody suggest what could be the similar code for emberjs **rc1**?

Thanks

Comment: What's your use case? I believe the router is isolated for a reason. If you just want to *transition to* another route, from within the controller you can do something like this `this.get('target').transitionTo('other.route')` and from within a route you simply do `this.transitionTo('other.route')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anybody suggest what could be the similar code for emberjs rc1?

Emberjs rc1 does not expose the router in this way.

As an alternative you should access router via local references.

- From a controller: this.get('target')
- From a view: this.get('controller.target')
- From a model: no. just don't do this.
- From the console: It is possible to [Access the new ember router in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109000/access-the-new-ember-router-in-the-console) but keep in mind that [App.container was not meant to be a public API](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/5becdc4467573f80a5c5dbb51d97c6b9239714a8)

It's not just the router, pretty much everything that used to be accessible via global constants is now hidden. This is because using global constants to access instances breaks encapsulation, and while that is fine for the console it should be avoided in your application code.

Comment: Using App.container (now __container__) may not be a very good idea from within ember.js... But what about using it when interfacing with other frameworks, legacy code, etc., would that be OK?

Comment: Supposed there could be a use case but I've not found one. Seems like you'd want to isolate legacy code as much as possible. So if accessing private methods like container is a bad idea from your ember code it is probably even worse to access it when interfacing with another framework.

Comment: but what if I need that an Ember app reacts to something that happened elsewhere? Is using Instrum entation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458287/how-to-fire-an-event-to-ember-from-another-framework/14508316#14508316) the right thing to do for this simple use case?

Comment: I think it depends. Can you be more specific?

Comment: For example, in my case I need to make Ember.js react to code called from and Android app through a WebView. So having a public interface between the JavaScript world and the Java world is a necessity. That interface may be a an encapsulated object but it needs to be able to make Ember.js router react to change the application state. This kind of use case is not very well defined in Ember. For example, AngularJS seems to do a better job at this by providing services (that could be my interface) and Dependency injection.

Comment: Gotcha. Hard to answer this one in comments - mind posting it as a new question?

Comment: Ok. Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310716/best-way-to-integrate-ember-js-with-external-code-e-g-androids-webview