# getting currentPath in ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

In Ember 2.0 controller will be deprecated.  How do I access the currentPath.  At the moment I am doing the following.

```
  needs: ["application"],

  routeName : function() {
    return this.get('controllers.application.currentPath');
  }.property('controllers.application.currentPath),
```

Comment: Just adding a side note for anybody coming across this.  Controllers are not deprecated and in fact are quite useful in organizing the data and actions in your component tree!  The other option is top level components to orchestrate your backend requests, top level actions and data/computed properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
applicationController: Ember.inject.controller("application"),
routeName : function() {
    return this.get('applicationController.currentPath');
}.property('applicationController.currentPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly ember 1.8 added the `routeName` property to route objects, you can access it from the route by calling `this.routeName` (I am assuming that is what you want since your cp is named so).

On a side note you should start using the new computed property syntax:

```
routeName: Ember.computed('controllers.application.currentPath', function() {
  return this.get('controllers.application.currentPath');
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the 3.9 API docs, here is how you would do it now.  Using the public APIs is probably recommended (currentRouteName, currentURL), but super easy to refactor like so for now.

```
export default Service.extend({
  router: service(),

  whereAmI: computed('router.currentRouteName', function() {
    return this.router._router.currentPath; // 'users.index'
  })
});
```

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/RouterService
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v3.9.0/packages/%40ember/-internals/routing/lib/system/router.ts#L1631